# GraphQL query returning duplicate results

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a GraphQL schema that returns orders and the products that are part of that order. I have added a filter to return only orders that contains products searched for by the user. This filter is done on a `icontains`.

However I have found that if a user searches for `angel` for example, and an order contains two or more products that contain the string `angel` it returns the order that many times duplicating the records returned to the frontend.

**Query:**

```json
{
  dateFilterList
  Purchases(first: 15, after: "", username_Icontains: "", PurchaseOrdersProductsOrderId_ProductName: "angel") {
    pageCursors {
      previous {
        cursor
      }
      first {
        cursor
        page
      }
      around {
        cursor
        isCurrent
        page
      }
      last {
        cursor
        page
      }
      next {
        cursor
      }
    }
    edges {
      node {
        id
        cmOrderId
        username
        date
        articles
        merchandiseValue
        shippingValue
        trusteeValue
        totalValue
        products {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              productId
              productName
              productNumber
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Json Response:**

```json
{
  "data": {
  ...
  "purchases": {
    ...
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "",
            "cmOrderId": 12345,
            "username": "UserA",
            "date": "2022-06-29T16:38:51",
            "articles": 40,
            "merchandiseValue": "",
            "shippingValue": "",
            "trusteeValue": "",
            "totalValue": "",
            "products": {
              "edges": [
                {
                  "node": {
                    "id": "",
                    "productId": "",
                    "productName": "Angel of Grace",
                    "productNumber": "1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "node": {
                    "id": "",
                    "productId": "",
                    "productName": "Angel of Sanctions",
                    "productNumber": "1"
                  }
                },
                ...
              ]
            }
          },
          "node": {
            "id": "",
            "cmOrderId": 12345,
            "username": "UserA",
            "date": "2022-06-29T16:38:51",
            "articles": 40,
            "merchandiseValue": "",
            "shippingValue": "",
            "trusteeValue": "",
            "totalValue": "",
            "products": {
              "edges": [
                {
                  "node": {
                    "id": "",
                    "productId": "",
                    "productName": "Angel of Grace",
                    "productNumber": "1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "node": {
                    "id": "",
                    "productId": "",
                    "productName": "Angel of Sanctions",
                    "productNumber": "1"
                  }
                },
                ...
              ]
            }
          },
          ...
```

**Schema:**

```py
# region Integration Purchase Orders
class PurchaseOrderFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = purchase_orders
        fields = {'date': ['gt', 'lt', 'isnull'], 'username': ['icontains'],}

    purchase_orders_products_order_id__product_name = CharFilter(lookup_expr="icontains")


class PurchaseOrderProductFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = purchase_orders_products
        fields = {"product_name": ["icontains"]}


class PurchasesProducts(DjangoObjectType):
    id = graphene.ID(source='pk', required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = purchase_orders_products
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)
        filterset_class = PurchaseOrderProductFilter


class Purchases(DjangoObjectType):
    id = graphene.ID(source='pk', required=True)
    products = DjangoFilterConnectionField(PurchasesProducts)

    class Meta:
        model = purchase_orders
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)
        filterset_class = PurchaseOrderFilter
        connection_class = ArtsyConnection

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_products(self, info, **kwargs):
        return purchase_orders_products.objects.filter(order_id=self.id).order_by('product_name').all()


class PurchasesQuery(ObjectType):
    date_filter_list = graphene.List(graphene.List(graphene.String))
    purchases = ArtsyConnectionField(Purchases)

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_date_filter_list(self, info, **kwargs):
        years = purchase_orders.objects.filter(user_id=info.context.user.id).annotate(year=ExtractYear('date'), month=ExtractMonth('date'), ).order_by().values_list('year', 'month').order_by('-year', '-month').distinct()
        return years

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_purchases(self, info, **kwargs):
        return purchase_orders.objects.filter(user_id=info.context.user.id).all().order_by("-date")


PurchasesSchema = graphene.Schema(query=PurchasesQuery)
# endregion
```

Comment: Should provide how you query your data (json response is not enough)

Comment: @jorzel I have added the Query to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

Your query is likely returning duplicate results. It's sometimes not enough to just call `.distinct()`.

## Solution

You must specify `DISTINCT ON <field>` as it seems your `id` field is returning an empty string. Consider a adding `.distinct('cmOrderId')` to your query.

I also notice that most of your `purchase_order_product` queries do not include `distinct`—consider adding the `.distinct('cmOrderId')` to all of these queries.

## Notes

Furthermore, I notice that you call `all()` on your `filter()` queries—it has no effect on the resulting object.

## References

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct